# How do i call an associated attribute from another model in a sql query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, postgresql, api

Im currently working on a rails application who has a local API where i request data from my main model Book.rb on a search functionality through an ajax request.

i want to be able to include a Category.rb attribute on a Book.rb SQL query.

The db structure goes like this.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :book_category_relations
   has_many :categories, through: :book_category_relations 
end

class BookCategoryRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :book
    belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books, through: :book_category_relations
    has_many :book_category_relations
end
```

Here is the query i perfom on my book.rb at this moment.

```
Book.rb
    scope :search, -> query { where("lower(title) LIKE ? OR lower(author) LIKE ? OR lower(publisher) LIKE ? OR lower(publication_year) LIKE ? OR lower(country_of_origin) LIKE ? OR lower(description) LIKE ? OR lower(category) LIKE ?", 
      "%#{query}%".downcase, "%#{query}%".downcase, "%#{query}%".downcase, "%#{query}%".downcase, "%#{query}%".downcase, "%#{query}%".downcase, "%#{query}%".downcase) }
end
```

And this is what my .json.jbuilder looks like.

```
app/views/api/books/index.json.jbuilder

json.array! @books do |book|
  json.title book.title
  json.author book.author
  json.publisher book.publisher
  json.image_url book.cover.url
  json.id book.id
  json.publication_year book.publication_year
  json.country_of_origin book.country_of_origin
  json.description book.description
  json.price book.price
  if book.categories[0] != nil
   json.category book.categories[0].name
  end
end
```

I want to be able to include the `Book.categories.name` into the scope i defined on the Book Model so i can search by the categories related to my Book Model.

I've tried:
1. lower(book.categories)
2. lower(book.category.name)

This is a view of the api passing `http://localhost:3000/api/books/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=diccionario`

```
[
 {
 title: "DICCIONARIO DEL ESPAÑOL JURIDICO",
 author: "Santiago Muñoz Machado",
 publisher: "Consejo General del Poder Judicial",
 image_url:      "/system/books/covers/000/",
 id: 30,
 publication_year: "2016",
 country_of_origin: "España",
 description: null,
 price: "175.0",
 category: [
   {
    name: "Diccionarios"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Any tip, hint or reference is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :search, -> query { joins(:categories).where("lower(title) LIKE ? OR lower(author) LIKE ? OR lower(publisher) LIKE ? OR lower(publication_year) LIKE ? OR lower(country_of_origin) LIKE ? OR lower(description) LIKE ? OR lower (categories.name) LIKE ?",
  "%#{query}%".downcase, "%#{query}%".downcase, "%#{query}%".downcase, "%#{query}%".downcase, "%#{query}%".downcase, "%#{query}%".downcase, "%#{query}%".downcase) }
```

So, i was missing a 'joins(:categories)' before my where.

The rails active records do this automatically when we define in our model a relationship like :has_many or :belongs_to, but it was necessary to declare it on my scope because my sql query responds to a javascript function, not a rails method.